# Keycloak setup on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, keycloak-connect

I am using this link to have a Keycloak setup on my K8s cluster in Azure cloud.
https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-kube

Even after following all the steps successfully, unable to get the Keycloak Admin console or Keycloak account on my browser. I have minicube on my machine, also enabled the ingress addon.

Deployed Keycloak deployment and service and also ingress.

I do the echo :
KEYCLOAK_URL=https://keycloak.$(minikube ip).nip.io &&

```
echo "Keycloak:                 $KEYCLOAK_URL" &&
echo "Keycloak Admin Console:   $KEYCLOAK_URL/admin" &&
echo "Keycloak Account Console: $KEYCLOAK_URL/realms/myrealm/account" &&
echo ""
```

and get the successful output without errors:

```
Keycloak:                         https://keycloak.<IP>.nip.io
Keycloak Admin Console:           https://keycloak.<IP>.nip.io:8443/admin
Keycloak Account Console:         https://keycloak.<IP>.nip.io/realms/myrealm/account
```

But when I try opening the Admin console link or Keycloak link, in my browser it does not open.

Not sure as what am I missing and what else is supposed to be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out my YAML files to deploy the Keycloak on Kubernetes.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.0
        env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          value: "admin"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          value: "admin"
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
        - name: DB_VENDOR
          value: POSTGRES
        - name: DB_ADDR
          value: postgres
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: keycloak
        - name: DB_USER
          value: root
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name : KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT
          value : "80"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT
          value: "443"
        - name : KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME
          value : keycloak.harshmanvar.tk #replace with ingress URL
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        - name: https
          containerPort: 8443
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /auth/realms/master
            port: 8080
```

https://github.com/harsh4870/Keycloack-postgres-kubernetes-deployment

Feel free to refer this article for more : https://faun.pub/keycloak-kubernetes-deployment-409d6ccd8a39