# JDBC driver Exception issue is coming in keycloak service

Tags: kubernetes, mysql-workbench, keycloak, helm3

I'm trying to configure my keycloak-18 running on helm-chart with external mysql database-8 version.

here is my helm chart file

values.yaml file

```
image:
  repository: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: "18.0.0"
  args: ["start-dev"
       ,"--log-console-color=true"
       ,"--db=mysql"
       ,"--db-username=****"
       ,"--db-password=*****"
       ,"--db-url=jdbc:mysql://194.148.0.57/keycloakblockchain"
      ]
```

**deployment file**

```
- name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          args: {{ .Values.args }}
```

**ERROR**

````
2022-05-05 02:43:50,762 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://194.148.0.57/keycloakblockchain

2022-05-05 02:43:38,765 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA Startup Thread: keycloak-default) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://194.148.0.57/keycloakblockchain
    at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getJdbcConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:191)
    at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getXAConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:352)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:216)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:513)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:494)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1126)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)```
````

Comment: YOu should take a look at this https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak#using-an-existing-secret

Comment: @Abhijeet thank you for the reply. I have checked this link and tried this also but it does not work, I have managed to configure my local MySQL database with keycloak service which is running on Kubernetes, but when I'm using helm to create a chart and configure the service with external database it's giving error.

Comment: As it is not able to find the mysql driver.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71376938/5525824

Comment: this link is only referring to the kubernetes yaml which i already done, i'm using helm for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try **removing** the **jdbc:** and just use the **mysql:/** instead

```
"--db-url=mysql://194.148.0.57/keycloakblockchain"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Took me some time to notice that I had a typo in `"KC_DB=mysql"` while building the production image.

If you used the Dockerfile from here: https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers

than you should just need to change the `KC_DB` environment var to mysql.

My Docker file:

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2 as builder

ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_PROXY=edge
ENV KC_DB=mariadb
ENV KC_DB_URL_PROPERTIES=characterEncoding=UTF-8
ENV KC_TRANSACTION_XA_ENABLED=false
ENV KC_CACHE_CONFIG_FILE=cache-ispn-jdbc-ping.xml

COPY cache-ispn-jdbc-ping.xml /opt/keycloak/conf/cache-ispn-jdbc-ping.xml
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi/releases/download/2.5.3/keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.3.jar -o /opt/keycloak/providers/keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.3.jar
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start"]
```

My docker-compose.yml (I used to test locally):

```yaml
  [...]

  keycloak:
    build:
      context: ./keycloak
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: 'keycloak'
    restart: 'no'
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.services.keycloak.loadbalancer.server.port=8080'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.keycloak.entrypoints=http'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.keycloak.rule=Host(`sso.localhost`) || Host(`sso.${HOSTNAME}`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.keycloak.service=keycloak@docker'
    environment:
      KC_EXTERNAL_IP: 172.21.2.2
      KC_EXTERNAL_PORT: 9600
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: db-keycloak
      KC_DB_URL_PORT: 3306
      KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: db
      KC_DB_USERNAME: user
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: pass
      KC_PROXY: edge
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: root
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      internal:
        ipv4_address: 172.21.2.2
    expose:
      - '8080'
      - '9600'
    ports:
      - '82:8080'
    depends_on:
      - db-keycloak

  [...]
```

Comment: can you please provide me with the Environment Variables of Logs and LOgs file? for keycloak to build an prod image

Comment: hi @t00manysecrets, Can you provide me the details i mentioned above

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am very sorry for answering that late. I don't use stackoverflow very often but I've updated my answer. Since then we moved to mariadb with galerea so some of the environment variabales may be not necessary for you (KC_TRANSACTION_XA_ENABLED=false)